# Pentaho writing to log but not text file

Tags: pentaho, data-integration

I have a transformation that is successfully writing the first row to the log file.
However the same transformation is not writing the first row to a text file.
The text file remains blank.

Does anyone know why this may be?
[image]

edited - only focusing on the applications to run and set pm variable transformations, as the other transformations are replications of set pm variable but for different fields

Comment: can you please paste you mapping here, without looking into it its really hard to tell what is going wrong,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Set Variables step is distributing its rows over the two follow-up steps in a round-robin way, which is the default setting in PDI.

Right-click the Set Variables step and under Data Movement, select Copy. That will send all rows to BOTH steps. You should see a documents icon on the hops then.

Comment: thanks, but still nothing is appearing in the text file output?

Comment: Does the file appear when you run the job and it's not present yet? Do headers get written?